# Issue with AWSCognito/DynamoDB (Unauthenticated access - not supported)

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

I am trying to use `AWSCognito` and `DynamoDB` in an `iOS` app.

I have followed [this document](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/building-fine-grained-authorization-using-amazon-cognito-user-pools-groups/).

appearently with no problem until step 5 (*Create a user pool group*).

For:

```
Step 6: Amazon DynamoDB row-level authorization
```

I don't quite understand what I am supposed to do.

When running this Swift code:

```
dynamoDbObjectMapper.save(newMyObject!, completionHandler: {
    (error: Error?) -> Void in

    if let error = error {
        print("Amazon DynamoDB Save Error: \(error)")
        return
    }
    print("An item was saved.")
})
```

I get this error:

```
Amazon DynamoDB Save Error: Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoIdentityErrorDomain 
Code=8 "(null)" UserInfo={__type=NotAuthorizedException, message=Unauthenticated 
access is not supported for this identity pool.}
```

But I do not intend to have "Unauthenticated access".
I was expecting to be asked for a username/password at some point.

I must have either done something wrong on the way or not done something I should've done.

The fact is I have no experience setting up AWSCognito/DynamoDB to work together.

Comment: It's look like problem is in your `amazon-cognito` setup.

Comment: Well, if you write so, that may well be true. But what do you suggest I check first?
I have created a user that I can see.